# Socket IO leave room but still receiving events for that room such as disconnects from that room

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, peerjs

I am trying to create a video call application using peerJS and Socket.io. Lets say I have 2 users, User A, User B, and 2 rooms, Room 1 and Room 2.

User A joins both rooms at once to see if anyone picks up. User A joins Room 1 and Room 2 with socket.join, Room 1 answers, so I do socket.leave("room2") to leave the room. I logged the rooms before and after and User A does successfully leave Room 2.

Now User B wants to call but only Room 2 is available, so he joins Room 2.

Now when User A "ends" his call and reloads the page, it causes Room 2 to be refreshed. This should not be the case as he has .leave() the room earlier and that room should not be receiving any events like disconnect.

What is have noticed is that .leave() doesnt really leave the room, i.e. the callbacks are not removed. Is there any way to completely break the link once the user as left the room?

```
io.on('connection', socket => {

    socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
        socket.join(roomId)
        //socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)
        socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId);

        console.log("socketId " + socket.id + " connected to room " + roomId);


        socket.on('leave-room', (roomId) => {
            console.log(socket.adapter.rooms);
            socket.leave(roomId);
            console.log("socketId " + socket.id + " left room " + roomId);

            console.log(socket.adapter.rooms);

            // Tried this but if it disconnects later, other user in the room won't receive the message as        
            // disconnect event does not trigger
            //socket.removeAllListeners("disconnect");
        })

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {

            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("user-disconnected", userId);
            console.log("socketId " + socket.id + " disconnected from room " + roomId);
        })
    })
})
```

I tried removing the disconnect callback, which make the outcome to what I wanted but at the expense of the disconnect event not triggering when i want it to.

Comment: Don't nest the socket.on handlers

Comment: Are you sure that roomId is the same on join and leave? If the roomId is different is these two calls then the leave will fail.